# How to handle a binary data response in WebView

Tags: android

My activity has an intent filter to pick up a specific url and open it in a WebView control, which brings user to an auth page (user name/password). After authentication is done user will get a binary stream response (file). Is there a way to handle that response and read data from the stream?

I tried to setup a custom WebViewClient with the overridden shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, but app doesn't get there.

```
@Override 
mMyWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
mMyWebView.loadUrl("http://xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxx/getCert");

...
private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading  (WebView  view, String  urlConection)
    {
       // break point here doesn't stop debugger
       return true;
    }
}
```

neither works

```
mMyWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading  (WebView  view, String  urlConection)
    ....
});
```

Server reacts on requests in the same way from both My app and build-in browser. Build-in browser starts to download file received in response, but my app doesn't do anything and doesn't hit breakpoint inside CustomWebClient. 
This is a separate app just to test this piece nothing else interferes with it. INTERNET & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions added.

**EDIT: Mar 8**
Gave up. Will go with httpClient.

Comment: Good question, i'd like to know if this is possible. Unfortunately, you don't get a lot of control of the web pages the WebView just renders them. The *only* way I know how to do this would be by implementing PhoneGap to integrate the web code with the app.

Comment: That is annoying if it is true. There are options yet to rewrite implementation of WebView (probably not trivial) or go with WebServices and implement communication via HttpClient

Comment: Your code seems all right, and the breakpoint should hit... You must have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement this method of WebView?

void    setDownloadListener(DownloadListener listener)
Register the interface to be used when content can not be handled by the rendering engine, and should be downloaded instead.

Comment: Good point, thanks. My app indeed get notified that content should be downloaded instead of rendered. But question still ... how to handle downloading?